# Which is the better leaving group: R- or H-?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I don't know how to compare them. So many factors involved. According to me, R- should be better leaving group, as it is more electronegative than H, but on the other hand, R- is very unstable due to +I effects.

Answer (score 2):

R- is very vague. $\ce{-CH3}$ is a terrible leaving group, but $\ce{-CCl3}$ is a fair nucleofuge. "Leaving groups" typically means nucleofuge, which is a leaving group that takes the electrons from the broken bond with it as it leaves. $\ce{-H}$ makes for a poor nucleofuge, $\ce{H-}$ (hydride), but it is a common electrofuge, $\ce{H+}$, which is the opposite of a nucleofuge.

I just realized you might have meant $\ce{R-}$ and $\ce{H-}$ in your title question. In that case, you're still going to want to specify what "R" stands for, but $\ce{H-}$ is a very poor leaving group.